# Get the filename before download

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
demo_id = 'demoid=25044'

download_link = "http://www.hltv.org/interfaces/download.php?"+demo_id

print download_link

with open(demo_id+'.rar', 'wb') as handle:
    response = requests.get(download_link, stream=True)

    print response.headers['Content-Type']

    if not response.ok:
    # Something went wrong
        print "fcuk"

    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        handle.write(block)
```

If I to the link:
http://www.hltv.org/interfaces/download.php?demoid=25044
Then it get prompted with a download and a filename for that.
Is there anyway to retrieve that filename?

Comment: [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header?

Comment: Please, fix your example - you're missing imports and I guess there may be something else missing too. In general, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also, show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will fetch the filename without downloading the file for this situation:

```
import requests
import os

demo_id = 'demoid=25044'

download_link = "http://www.hltv.org/interfaces/download.php?"+demo_id
downloadheaders =  requests.head(download_link)
header = downloadheaders.headers['location']
name = header.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
print name
```